# full file path for zipped folder in python

Tags: python, file, path, zip

I have the following code that is trying to get the full file path (including the folder):

```
import zipfile
import os
import sys

zipped_files_dir = 'Z:\Dev\some_files'

def get_folder_names():
    path_list = []
    for folder_name in os.listdir(zipped_files_dir):
        path_list.append(folder_name)
    return path_list

def get_folder_directories(folder_list):
    for folder in folder_list:
        pathname = os.path.abspath(folder)
        print(pathname)

def main():
    get_folder_directories(get_folder_names())

>>>Z:\Dev\new_folder.zip
```

My problem is that I should have "\some_files\new_folder.zip" in the returned directory.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `os.path.join(zipped_files_dir, folder)` in the `get_folder_directories` function:

```
import zipfile
import os
import sys

zipped_files_dir = 'Z:\Dev\some_files'

def get_folder_names():
    path_list = []
    for folder_name in os.listdir(zipped_files_dir):
        path_list.append(folder_name)
    return path_list

def get_folder_directories(folder_list):
    for folder in folder_list:
        pathname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(zipped_files_dir, folder))
        print(pathname)

def main():
    get_folder_directories(get_folder_names())
```

---

Or, `path_list.append(os.path.join(zipped_files_dir, folder_name))` in `get_folder_names()`:

```
import zipfile
import os
import sys

zipped_files_dir = 'Z:\Dev\some_files'

def get_folder_names():
    path_list = []
    for folder_name in os.listdir(zipped_files_dir):
        path_list.append(os.path.join(zipped_files_dir, folder_name))
    return path_list

def get_folder_directories(folder_list):
    for folder in folder_list:
        pathname = os.path.abspath(folder)
        print(pathname)

def main():
    get_folder_directories(get_folder_names())
```

Comment: Must disagree, you should do os.path.join in get_folder_name.

Answer (score 1):

Chown has the correct solution.

In your code you pass abs_path the string "new_folder.zip". But abs_path doesn't know where it came from, so it figure it must be in the current working directory which is why you get r"Z:\Dev\new_folder.zip". You need to use os.path.join to combine the filename with the path you find it in.